# Accepting Dai or an any ERC20 token as a payment

Tags: solidity, dai

I have created an ERC20 token and want to make it payable with DAI.

I read some of the related questions but did not found any proper answer.

As dai is an ERC20 token so, how can I accept any token as payment instead of ether?

`function () external payable {}`

this accepts only ether, right?

sorry in advance for my English and little understanding of solidity

Comment: Your users should call the `approve` function on the DAI contract, passing to it your contract address as the custodian (i.e., the one being approved). They should do so before they call your contract's `buy` function, which will first call the `transferFrom` function on the DAI contract, passing to it `msg.sender` as the address to transfer DAI tokens from, `address(this)` as the address to transfer DAI tokens to, and the desired amount (which you would need to calculate, I suppose based on the amount that your user wants to buy (which the user will also need to pass to your `buy` function)).

Comment: Of course, if you use `address(this)` as the address to transfer DAI tokens to, then it means that the tokens will be transferred to your contract, and since you don't have a private key for it, you'll need to implement an internal mechanism (function) which will allow you to extract those tokens. Alternatively, instead of `address(this)` you can you some state-variable of `address` type, which you can preconfigure somewhere in your contract (for example, in the constructor).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can achieve this:

```
IERC20 public daiInstance;
uint256 public totalSupply;
mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

constructor(IERC20 _daiInstance) public {
    daiInstance = _daiInstance;
}

function buyXXX(uint256 daiAmount) external {
    uint256 xxxAmount = toXXX(daiAmount);
    bool success = daiInstance.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), daiAmount);
    require(success, "buy failed");
    totalSupply = totalSupply.add(xxxAmount);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].add(xxxAmount);
}

function sellXXX(uint256 xxxAmount) external {
    uint256 daiAmount = toDAI(xxxAmount);
    totalSupply = totalSupply.sub(xxxAmount);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(xxxAmount);
    bool success = daiInstance.transfer(msg.sender, daiAmount);
    require(success, "sell failed");
}

function toXXX(uint256 daiAmount) internal view returns (uint256) {
    // do some logic here
}

function toDAI(uint256 xxxAmount) internal view returns (uint256) {
    // do some logic here
}
```

Before calling your `buyXXX` function, your users will need to call the `approve` function on the DAI contract, passing to it your contract address as the custodian (i.e., the one being approved).

Of course, since you use `address(this)` as the destination to transfer the user's DAI tokens to, those tokens will be transferred to your contract. And since you don't have a private key for it, you'll need to implement an internal mechanism (function) which will allow you to extract those tokens. Alternatively, instead of `address(this)`, you can add to your contract a state-variable of `address` type, which you will be able pre-configure somewhere in your contract (for example, in the constructor).

Comment: is daiInstance is an address of DAI smart contract?

Comment: @iamsujit: Yes. You could technically deploy several DAI smart contracts. We typically refer to the source code as "contract", and to every deployed entity as "instance". Because in many cases there is no sense in deploying more than one instance of a given contract (for example, if the contract represents a token), people often refer to both things (the source code and the deployed byte-code) as "contract".

Comment: @goodvibration do you know if its possible to accept more than one token using IERC20 interface in a single function? Im hving troubles with this currently as it can only accept one type of token once.

Comment: @KonstantinSmirnov of course you can just handle each token with a separate function and call the IERC20 instansiation with the correct contract address on the chain that you are on (ie Arbitrum One's token might be different than mainnet, always check to confirm)