# How do I make it possible so that my contract will accept USDC tokens

Tags: contract-development, usdc

this will be done as a fee for entry to a raffle. Is this done through interfacing the USDC contract or by interfacing the ERC20 contract?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accepting Dai or an any ERC20 token as a payment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/78904/accepting-dai-or-an-any-erc20-token-as-a-payment)